# How to uppercase only Latin characters, leaving others as it is?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to uppercase only Latin characters, leaving others as it is?

I want to sort objects, here is my code it is case-insensitive:

```
objects = ['факультет', 'Worm', 'Фонарь', 'word', 'Фонтан']
objects.sort(key=lambda x: x.upper(), reverse=False)
print(objects)
```

But I have to sort in Latin case-insensitive and non-Latin case-sensitive:

This is what I get:

```
['word', 'Worm', 'факультет', 'Фонарь', 'Фонтан']
```

Latin and non-Latin sorted case-insensitive

This is what I'm trying to match:

```
['word', 'Worm', 'Фонарь', 'Фонтан', 'факультет']
```

Latin sorted case-insensitive, non-Latin sorted case-sensitive

I know this is exactly behavior from Python 2, but I use Python 3.

Comment: My line is just for context `.upper()`  works correctly, but I need uppercase only Latin characters.

Comment: @Pychopath added to the post

Comment: Seems you have to split the data into two lists, sort them seperately and add them together afterwards.

Comment: What do you mean with Latin characters? Only the 26 from A to Z, or something like [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode)?

Comment: @Pychopath Yes, from A to z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as abc, ascii_uppercase as ABC

table = str.maketrans(abc, ABC)
blocks.sort(key=lambda s: s.translate(table))
```

Another:

```
import re

blocks.sort(key=lambda s: re.sub('[a-z]+', lambda m: m[0].upper(), s))
```

Answer (score 2):

Treat the strings different in your key function. If the first character (I assume that's enough to check) is an ASCII letter then apply `upper()` otherwise take the string as it is.

```
import string

objects = ['факультет', 'Worm', 'Фонарь', 'word', 'Фонтан']
objects.sort(key=lambda x: x.upper() if x[0] in string.ascii_letters else x, reverse=False)
print(objects)
```

This will give you `['word', 'Worm', 'Фонарь', 'Фонтан', 'факультет']`

---

If you want to check if all characters are ASCII letters then use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

```
objects.sort(key=lambda x: x.upper() if all(c in string.ascii_letters for c in x) else x, reverse=False)
```

Comment: Seems to be good, but what if it starts from a number like this: `['1факультет', 'Worm', '1Фонарь', 'word', '1Фонтан']` maybe re will help, I'll give a try.

Comment: I added another solution. If this is not what you need then please specify what should happen to those mixed strings.

Comment: Looks like Pychopath's solution is better, but thanks anyway